# Как посмотреть изменения, сделанные в терминале при установке приложения?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Допустим после выполнения команды

```
sudo apt install curl
```

как можно посмотреть все новые файлы, которые были созданы?
кроме системных процессов, т.е. к примеру из папки /proc не интересует информация

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18844

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
$ apt --help
...
  content          - List files contained in a package
...

$ apt content curl
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/curl
/usr/share/doc/curl/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/curl/copyright
/usr/share/doc/curl/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
/usr/share/zsh
/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions
/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_curl
```

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что этот способ не учёт вещи вроде /etc, update-alternatives и прочие радости из pre/postinstall скриптов